# Store brute-force IP addresses

Tags: login, security, ip

How can I store IP addresses which try to brute-force the login section or to login too frequent too fast?

I need to store all IPs, then use them in another application, sort of like a learning routine.

**UPDATE #1:**

Here's a scenario (pseudo-code):

```
function my_wp_login_failed($username) {
    store($username);
    store($ipAddress);
}
add_action('wp_login_failed', 'my_wp_login_failed');
```

How can I do this for all attack vectors?

**UPDATE #2:**

I need IP addresses trying to access the site more than X times get blocked for at least Y time. The initial phase will simply store these IP addresses.

**UPDATE #3:**

I have found this plugin - https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-fail2ban/trunk/wp-fail2ban.php - which might do the job. I will need to rewrite it in order to pass the IP information to a database or a flat file.

Comment: That may not be a good idea. Imagine if there's a DDoS attack. Your Database will be overwhelmed.

Comment: I know, but this is an experimental app. The code would eventually pass all IPs to a third-party app.

Comment: @Fayaz and he can clear that db table after some time, I guess...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż yes, this is a proof of concept. All data gets written to a log file on the server. It might not be the final behaviour, but I need it like this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wp_login_failed` action for that purpose... It's called at the end of `wp_authenticate`, if user credentials were incorrect.

```
function my_log_brute_force( $username ) {
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // store that info somewhere
    file_put_contents( 'bf-log.txt', date('c') . "\t{$ip_address}\t{$username}\n", FILE_APPEND );
}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_log_brute_force' );
```

Also this article may be helpful: [Getting real IP address in PHP](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html)

Comment: I have added a sample code, similar to yours. What about other attack vectors? The comment form? The registration form? The forgot password form? Can I do the same using a similar action? I want to have all bases covered.

Comment: What kind of attacks? Brute-force attacks trying to guess password? You don't have to secure other forms - WordPress always uses the same function to check credentials, so `wp_login_failed` will get called...

Comment: I am trying to detect frequent/fast attacks from the same IP. Let's say an IP address is trying to post 100 comments per second. How can I capture that IP address? Or an IP trying to create an account?

Comment: You have to check for all of such attacks and add them to the log. You can also try to monitor all requests - real users don't generate to many requests per second...

Comment: I know, that's why I was asking. I have updated my question with: "I need IP addresses trying to access the site more than X times get blocked for at least Y time. The initial phase will simply store these IP addresses." Your answer only covers one scenario.

Comment: @Ciprian So you should use server-side firewall and not PHP code or WordPress plugin.

Comment: For this experiment, I need PHP. I could use Fail2Ban or iptables, but I need pure PHP for this.

Comment: It has everything to do with WordPress as I need all hooks related to WordPress actions, such as logging in, registering, commenting.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, although it's only 10% of what I need. I'll research the rest. Thank you.

Comment: @Ciprian take a look at your question and then at updates - updates changed it completely and in this broader form it should be closed as “too broad”... List of all actions and filter is public and there is no point in copying it here. And question about “all possible vectors of attacking a site” is definitely to broad...

Comment: All possible vectors meaning WordPress-related, such as logging in, registering, commenting or interacting via XML-RPC. Maybe I'm missing something, but they're not too many. Also, list of all actions and filters only for the actions previously described.

Comment: @Ciprian almost every action can be potential attack. If you include XSS attacks, then every action is... So you’ll have to log every request to WP (or any other site). But if you take only bruteforce attacks trying to guess login (and that is what you asked in your question), then my answer should be helpful...